# FB wall posting OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i have integrated the feed post PHP-SDK by using the following set of codes

```
$attachment =  array(
    'access_token' => $accestoken,
    'message' => "Favorite Restaurant is ".$business['name'].$business['location']['city']."-What is yours? ",
    'name' => $business['name'],
    'link' => $business['personal_url'],
    'description' => "<b>myTaste || real restaurant reviews, share your taste on myTaste</b>",
    'picture'=> "http://mysite.com/images/gui/header/mytaste.gif"
);  
$facebook->api("/".$usid."/feed", "post",$attachment);
```

Everything worked great for one day, but today it was showing the following error codes.

> Uncaught OAuthException: (#341) Feed
>   action request limit reached thrown in
>   /hsphere/local/home/mysite.com/include/3rdparty/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php

Uncaught OAuthException: (#210) User not visible thrown in /hsphere/local/home/mysite.com/include/3rdparty/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php

Comment: Put your code in side code blocks so that we can read it more easily.

Answer (score 2):

Your application seems to have reached the limits of interaction.

1. Login to facebook
2. Visit http://www.facebook.com/insights/
3. Select your App
4. Click on API
5. Look for API Throttling tab.

And see what limits your have reached.

To find out how to fix this and what exactly causes this you can read more about it in these threads on Facebook's developer forum:

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=95309
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewforum.php?id=24

Comment: Can you please tell me where should i exactly check this, i can't found any tab like this in my applciation.

Comment: the error message throws differently each time. Can anyone suggest what's the problem with code        my                                                              Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#210) User not visible thrown in /hsphere/local/home/mysite/include/3rdparty/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php